# Find the answer of following intergal?

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

What are the steps to integrate the following integral involving the delta function?

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}\delta(t-2)\,dt$$

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but doesn't this (by definition of the delta function) mean that this is $f(2) = e^{-2^2} = e^{-4}$???

Comment: Same comment as Jared. I would say that the integral is 0 since $e^{-t^2}\delta (t-2)=0$ a.e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a formal point of view, the Dirac Function $\delta(x)$ is defined as:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\delta(x)dx=f(0)$$
So you have:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\delta(x-x_0)dx=f(x_0)$$
In your case you get: 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp(-t^2)\delta(t-2)dt=\exp(-2^2)$$